# Building Openh264 library with android NDK21 for pjsip android fails?

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip, ndk-build, openh264

I am building Openh264 library as a video codec for pjsip.

```
    make OS=android NDKROOT=/home/Username/Downloads/android-ndk-r21d-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r21d TARGET=android-28
```

> ```
> Error
> ```

```
> build/platform-android.mk:51: *** Compiler not found, bad NDKROOT or
> ARCH?.  Stop.
```

I have no success in building library for openh264 using android ndk 21,20 and 19
It doesn’t require entire environment for building this library .. just ndk and openh264 library .

> **below are the reference i have used for the  compilation**

1  Info  on how to compile  link

https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1947

2  Android ndk link

https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads

3 OpenH264 library link

https://github.com/cisco/openh264/archive/v1.6.0.zip

those are three details required to build a library .

Any help would be highly appreciated ...

Comment: Can you try with a different NDK version?

Comment: @AanalMehta Thanks for the reply and i do not have success in version 20 as well as 19 . Any help would be highly appreciated . updated details info of how i compile as well

Comment: Hi, do you have working android example of openh264?